# WooCommerce website cart connected with the 2nd WooCommerce Website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

is it possible to connect the 1st WooCommerce website cart with the 2nd WooCommerce website cart?

so the idea is, if someone selected some products on the 1st website, the items in the cart is inserted to the 2nd website cart as well. Is this possible? or any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom cookie whenever a cart item is added on 1st website. Populate that custom cookie with product skus inside that cart. So, whenever the user loads the 2nd website, there should be a plugin that loads product ids in the custom cookie and adds them in the cart programatically.

On website 1, you can add the following code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'set_cart_cookie' );

function set_cart_cookie()
{
  global $woocommerce;
  $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
  $item_skus[];

  foreach($items as $item => $values) {
         $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_sku());
         $item_skus[]=$_product;
     }
  setcookie("shared_cart", $item_skus, time()+30*24*60*60);
}
```

And on website 2, use this code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'read_cart_cookie' );

function read_cart_cookie()
{
  if(isset($_COOKIE['shared_cart'])){
    $cookie_skus=$_COOKIE['shared_cart'];
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    foreach ($cookie_skus as $sku)
    {

      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku ));

    }
  }
}
```

The code above is strictly for a scenario in which website 2 always follows the cookie contents set for website 1 for settings items in the car as I assume you can modify the code as you want. Also, items in website 1 should have the exact same skus as items in website 2 to make my code work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but it doesnt working on my side, and also the `set_cart_cookie()` function gave me an error because using the `init` hook, so I changed it to `plugins_loaded`, but it doesnt working, can you please help? thanks

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya Can you please tell me what error are you getting?

Comment: it's telling me the WooCommerce plugin is not loaded yet, so that's why I change the hook to `plugins_loaded` but now i already make it works using your idea with cookies, thank you! :) +1 for the idea